# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, strong-parameters

I have done the following things. I installed strong_parameters gem.

1)I created a initializer and added the following line ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection)

2)I removed attr_accessible from model.

Then i was tried to create a new record, it's was not going to the create method itself. it was giving ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes error. Please explain me what could be the problem?

Please find the code below:

**config/initializers/strong_parameters.rb**

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection)
```

**app/models/role.rb**

```
 class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :name, :description
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}
 end
```

**app/controllers/roles_controller.rb**

```
 class RolesController < ApplicationController

  def create
   @role = Role.new(role_params)
   if @role.save
     redirect_to roles_path, notice: t('Role was successfully created.', default: 'Role was successfully created.')
  else
     render action: "new"
  end
 end

 private

 def role_params
  params.require(:role).permit(:name,:description)
 end

end
```

**EDIT** : Please find the error message:

[image]

Comment: post your `params` from the `log`

Comment: @RajarshiDas i have updated the question with the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with cancan gem. I tried the below skip_load_resource. It's working now.

```
 load_and_authorize_resource skip_load_resource only: [:create]
```